# for loop to print dimensions of files in a list

Tags: r, for-loop

```
temp <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx')
list <- lapply(temp,read_excel)
```

The above list has 12 files. I want to check the dimensions of each of those 12 files, i.e. number of rows and columns in each file.

```
for(i in length(list)){
  print(dim(list[[i]]))
}

[1] 12533    49
```

The above for loop only gives me output of the last file, whereas I need the for loop to give me dimension of each 12 files.

Could someone please let me know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `for` loop to

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
   print(dim(list[[i]]))
}
```

since `1:length(list)` would create a sequence of numbers to loop over whereas `length(list)` would only give the length of the list (which is 12 in your case) and it would not generate the sequence.

Moreover, you don't even need a loop to do this. You could just use `lapply` and it would give you dimensions of the list.

```
lapply(list, dim)
```

For example,

```
list_df <- list(mtcars, iris)
lapply(list_df, dim)

#[[1]]
#[1] 32 11

#[[2]]
#[1] 150   5
```

On a side note, it is not a good practice to name your list as `list` since it is an internal R function.

Comment: If you want to use a `for`-loop, using `seq_along` is safer: if it turns out there are no files, `1:length(list)` means you iterate over `c(1,0)`, instead of skiping the loop.
But I agree lapply is better here.